# Why would an app generator be on npm and not yeoman? (ie. angular seed) Github vs npm vs Yeoman as distribution source for app start skeletons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, yeoman

Wanted to see if anyone can help clarify a few things in general using this angular-seed for example:

Angular-seed you can install it via github (git clone) or npm but not yeoman.

- Is a project like angular-seed on npm because - it was the first real distribution tool for full stack javascript stuff?
- This does not mean that it somehow can be used as a backend component? note: on angular-seed's npm page - links to same github page as the project home as the one in the tut below.
- Yeoman would be the primary place right now you would look for this type of package/app starter skeleton rather than github direct or some other source?

  Angular-seed is not on yeoman right now - would this (or a combo with project commit activity) defer you from using this project for an app starter?

Recently did the following angular + firebase [tut](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-angularjs-and-firebase--cms-22391). Angular-seed project is installed by using git clone on the tut. I remembered seeing angular-seed on npm and out of curiosity installed that in another folder to compare. Noticed similar structures but not the same. Some of the tree structure I included below.

```
myProjectFolder (installed from git clone)
  -angular-seed
    -app
      -components
      -view1
      -view2
      app.css
      app.js
      index.async.html
      index.html
    -e2e-tests
    -node-modules
    bower.json
    karma.config.js
    package.json

myProjectFolder (installed from npm)
  -node_modules
    -angular-seed
      -app
       -bower_components
       -css
       -img
       -js
       -partials
       -index.html
       -index-async.html
      README.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like the npm version it's outdated it says:
**Version    1.2.0 last updated a year ago** vrs the repo which was updated 26 days ago (from today)

If you look at the documentation indeed they have a different folder structure, maybe because they haven't updated the package information on npm, one weird thing is the npm package points to the same git repo.

regarding to your questions:

> it was the first real distribution tool for full stack javascript
>   stuff?

I'm not sure what do you mean by that, but I think it could be because bower didn't exist but that date or wasn't available at mainstream

> This does not mean that it somehow can be used as a backend component?

no isn't angular seed it's only related to the client side, if you want to look at some fullstack look at mean.js

> Yeoman would be the primary place right now you would look for this
>   type of package/app starter skeleton rather than github direct or some
>   other source?

yeoman is way more than a skeleton, is a scaffolder, probably the guys on the project don't want to implement that functionality. anyway I recommend you cg-angular which implements 'the best practices' for an angular project.

Comment: thx. I looked at the cg-angular that uses grunt, any recommendations that you know that uses gulp?

Comment: I have no experience with gulp, sorry about it!